# What do two left angle brackets mean?

Tags: c#, .net, list, for-loop, bitwise-operators

I saw a loop which I've never seen before:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << list.Count); i++)
```

I can't understand what `(1 << list.Count)` means, maybe someone could explain me this?

Comment: Yes. Definitely a duplicate. Also something that probably should've been googled first. Also, I can't believe the number of comments that call using shift operators "unreadable." Maybe if you had 10 of them on the same line or something, but a shift operator is a very, very basic operator and "<<" has been the pneumonic for it in many languages since the 1960s. It's the kind of thing you learn in the first week of a programming class. Using Math.Pow() instead of << for a power of two on an integer is the point at which I consider firing the programmer. You're talking hundreds of cycles vs. 1.